# Put body content in center

Tags: html, css

I use center tag, but it seems that is not standard in HTML 5. I tried to use CSS instead but it doesn't work for me! I expect in this example the div tag be displayed in center but it won't.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body style="text-align:center">
<div style="width:100px; height:30px; background-color:rgb(0,0,0)"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is center tag version: (it works)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<body>
<center>
<div style="width:100px; height:30px; background-color:rgb(0,0,0)"></div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `margin: auto` for your div

```
div {
    margin: auto;
    width:100px; 
    height:30px; 
    background-color:rgb(0,0,0)
}
```

Also it's better to give your `div` an `id` or class name to target it more accurately if your HTML markup become more complex as well as using external CSS instead of inline styles like what you're doing now.

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LBqEV/1/)**

Comment: Thanks a lot. it's working now! I use external css but write such just for this example.

Comment: Of course the 0 front of margin is not necessary. (margin: auto;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use css:

```
.window{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-140px;
    margin-left:-200px;
    width:400px;
    height:280px;
}
```

make sure you substract half of the width and height using margins. This way your div will be centered within the window the div is in.

Answer (score 0):

The div tag which you want to put in center in your body must be :

```
.div-class {
    margin: auto;
}
```

If you use margin top or bottom, you can do this way:

```
.div-class {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```